# Finding the limit inf./inf. form

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Find the limit of the sequence defined by

Lim $_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(2^n\cdot n!)^2}$

How to start?

Is there another way of showing this sequence is convergent without finding the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asymptotic of the central binomial coefficient is given by
$$\dbinom{2n}n \sim \dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{(n+1/2)\pi}}$$
Hence, we have that
$$\dfrac{(2n)!}{(2^n \cdot n!)^2} \sim \dfrac1{\sqrt{\pi (n+1/2)}}$$
This means
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(2n)!}{(2^n \cdot n!)^2} = 0$$

Comment: Is there another way to show this sequence is cgt.?

Answer (score 1):

To show the sequence is convergent without finding the limit:

- if $a_n = \dfrac{(2n)!}{(2^n\cdot n!)^2}$
- then $a_0=1$
- and $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = \dfrac{(2n)(2n-1)}{2^2n^2} = 1- \dfrac{1}{2n}$ which is between $0$ and $1$ for $n \ge 1$
- so $a_n$ represents a decreasing positive sequence and is therefore bounded below by $0$ and thus converges to a non-negative value

Answer (score 0):

Using Stirling's approximation, $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left (  \frac{n}{e}\right )^n$, we have

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n\cdot n!)^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{\pi n}\left (  \frac{2n}{e}\right )^{2n}}{\left (2^n\cdot  \sqrt{2\pi n}\left (  \frac{n}{e}\right )^n\right )^2}$$

Some cancelling will leave you with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{(2n)!}{(2^n\cdot n!)^2}=\dfrac{\prod_{r=1}^n(2r)}{2^n\cdot n!}\cdot\dfrac{\prod_{u=1}^n(2u-1)}{2^n\cdot n!}=\prod_{r=1}^n\dfrac{2r-1}{2r}$$

which is $\le\dfrac1{\sqrt{3n+1}}$  ([Proof](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/inequality.shtml#solution100))

**See also** :

[limit of $\sqrt[n]{\frac{1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}}$ using geometric mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310216/limit-of-sqrtn-frac1-cdot-3-cdots-2n-12-cdot-4-cdots-2n-using-geo)

[Convergent Series 2n-1/2n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044097/convergent-series-2n-1-2n)

[The lower bound](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/inequality.shtml)  of $\prod_{r=1}^n\dfrac{2r-1}{2r}$